# When does an open set $O$, for each point $x \in O$, contain a closed set containing $x$?

Tags: general-topology

Say I have an open set $A$ in some topology $\tau$. What assumptions to I need to place on $\tau$ to guarantee that, for each $x \in A$, there exists a closed set $C \subset A$ such that $x \in C$? Clearly, Euclidean space satisfies this property, but I imagine there are some pathological examples where this property doesn't hold.

EDIT:
I thought I would provide more details regarding Ulli's claim below:

> $X$ has this property if and only if it is $R_{0}$

Assume $X$ is $R_{0}$. Then the closure of $\{x\}$ contains only points topologically indistinguishable from $x$. Thus, since $x \in A$ and $A$ is open, the closure of $\{x\}$ is contained in $A$. Hence the property holds, with $C$ equal to the closure of $\{x\}$.

Now assume that the property desired holds. Then, since there is a closed set $C \subset A$ such that $x \in C$, the closure of $\{x\}$ must also be contained in $A$. Since this holds for every open set $A$, every point in the closure of $\{x\}$ is topologically indistinguishable from $x$, and thus $X$ is an $R_{0}$ space.

Comment: $X$ has this property, if and only if it is $R_0$.

Comment: Thanks @Ulli I have included a (trivial) proof of this claim in the question, which I assume is okay?

Comment: yes, that's ok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option would be to assume that the space is $T_1$, so that $\{x\}$ is a closed set.  That might not really be what you're looking for, though.

Perhaps a more satisfying solution is to ask that the space be regular - in a regular space given any $x$ and any open $A$ with $x \in A$ there is an open $V$ with $x \in V \subseteq \overline{V} \subseteq A$.

Comment: Ah yes, regularity seems like a reasonable assumption for my setting, thanks!